# Global footer in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

It seems impossible to create a global footer in an Ionic app.

Within a single page, you can use `<ion-footer>` and in turn, the `<ion-content>` component resizes itself using its `resize()` function, accounting for contained headers and footers, and *global* `<ion-tab>` allowing for tabs.

Having a `<ion-footer>` in `app.html` will **not** resize the content accordingly, causing for the footer to overlay the content.

Before I submit a pull request to the Ionic Framework's `Content.resize` method, does anyone know of a way to achieve a global footer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the height of the footer, you can style the `.ion-page` height to `calc(100% - #{$global-footer-height})`.

Example where global footer can be toggled on/off:

**app.component.ts**

```
@HostBinding('class.has-global-footer') public globalFooterEnabled: boolean = true;

constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar) {
    // You can toggle the footer from a Service or something.
    setTimeout(() => this.globalFooterEnabled = false, 5000);

    // myService.somethingHappened$
           .subscribe((toggle) => this.globalFooterEnabled = toggle);
}
```

**app.html** at the end:

```
<ion-footer class="global-footer" *ngIf="globalFooterEnabled">
    Hello World!
</ion-footer>
```

**app.scss**

```
$global-footer-height: 50px;

.has-global-footer .ion-page {
  height: calc(100% - #{$global-footer-height});
}

.global-footer {
  height: $global-footer-height;
}
```